# Regex for matching C# string literals

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that will match a string that contains name-value pairs of the form:

```
<name> = <value>, <name> = <value>, ...
```

Where <value> is a C# string literal. I already know the s that I need to find via this regular expression. So far I have the following:

```
regex = new Regex(fieldName + @"\s*=\s*""(.*?)""");
```

This works well, but it of course fails to match in the case where the string I am trying to match contans a <value> with an escaped quote. I am struggling to work out how to solve this, I *think* I need a lookahead, but need a few pointers. As an example, I would like to be able to match the value of the 'difficult' named value below:

```
difficult = "\\\a\b\'\"\0\f \t\v", easy = "one"
```

I would appreciate a decent explanation with your answers, I want to learn, rather than copy ;-)

Comment: Heh ... perhaps I should look at the SO sourcecode, just noticed the syntax highlighter clearly undersands string literals with escaped quotes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this to capture the key and value:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(@"(?:[^"]|"")*"|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*")
```

As a bonus, it also works on verbatim strings.

C# Examples:https://dotnetfiddle.net/vQP4rn

Here's an annotated version:

```
string pattern = @"
(\w+)\s*=\s*    # key =
(               # Capturing group for the string
    @""               # verbatim string - match literal at-sign and a quote
    (?:
        [^""]|""""    # match a non-quote character, or two quotes
    )*                # zero times or more
    ""                #literal quote
|               #OR - regular string
    ""              # string literal - opening quote
    (?:
        \\.         # match an escaped character,
        |[^\\""]    # or a character that isn't a quote or a backslash
    )*              # a few times
    ""              # string literal - closing quote
)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern, 
                                        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Note that the regular string allows all characters to be escaped, unlike in C#, and allows newlines. It should be easy to correct if you need validation, but it should be file for parsing.

Answer (score 3):

This should match only the string literal part (you can tack on whatever else you want to the beginning/end):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"((\\.)|[^\\\\\"])*\"");
```

and if you want a pattern which doesn't allow "multi-line" string literals (as C# string literals really are):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"((\\[^\n\r])|[^\\\\\"\n\r])*\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
@"  \s* = \s* (?<!\\)""  (.* ) (?<!\\)"""
```

It's almost like yours, but instead of using `""`, I used  `(?<!\\)""` to match when suffix \ is not present, so it won't match escaped quotes.

Comment: What about a string like  `"c:\"`, (escaped to `"c:\\"`) - your regex will not match the ending quote. Also, `(?<!\\)` does nothing before the first quote - if follows an equal sign or spaces.

Comment: Right, i didn't think about it ;)